# How to get sections using CoredataTableViewController?

Tags: iphone

I need to display data as two sections which is coming from Core data & I want to display the data using CoredataTableViewController. How can I do this?

Comment: There is nothing called CoredataTableViewController in iOS, its UITableViewController.Check the UITableViewController class reference in apple docs, you will find the solution.

Answer (score 3):

CoreDataTableViewController is a class available from the [Stanford CS193P class download site](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2010-fall) (see lecture 12). To use sections, you need to specify the sectionNameKeyPath when you create your NSFetchedResultsController. The sectionNameKeyPath is the name of the attribute in your data model that is used to divide up your sections.

Comment: Meanwhile there is a new download ([Fall 2011](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/downloads-2010-fall))